# Server to server automatic copy and paste feature

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, discord-jda

I'm helping a friend set up a server and was wondering if it was possible to copy and paste the messages on one server to another without being an admin on one of them?

Comment: You only need read message permission to "copy" and send message to "paste" so yes, this can be done without admin.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the messages to and from one server, you'd want to use webhooks to move them across and preserve the username. A feature like this has been implemented in various discord bots, but if you want to create your own then here is a discord.js example of how to do so: https://anidiots.guide/discord-webhooks.

What you'd want to do is to wait for the message event, then get (or create) a webhook from the other server with the user's name, then send the message contents in that webhook.